# Amazon S3 recursive copy fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, amazon-iam, aws-cli

I am trying to fetch folder from my S3 bucket, but somehow cannot figure out why it fails.

I call

```
aws s3 cp s3://somebucket . --recursive
```

and get

> fatal error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the
>   ListObjects operation: Access Denied

If I try to simulate these actions with the same user

```
aws iam simulate-principal-policy --policy-source-arn arn:aws:iam::123324234234:user/user1 --action-names iam:ListBucket iam:GetObject iam:PutObject --resource-arns arn:aws:s3:::somebucket
```

it drops `Allowed` everywhere

```
 {
     "EvaluationResults": [
         {
             "EvalActionName": "iam:ListBucket",
             "EvalResourceName": "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket",
             "EvalDecision": "allowed",
             "MatchedStatements": [
                 {
                     "SourcePolicyId": "AdministratorAccess",
                     "StartPosition": {
                         "Line": 3,
                         "Column": 17
                     },
                     "EndPosition": {
                         "Line": 8,
                         "Column": 6
                     }
                 }
             ],
             "MissingContextValues": []
         },
         {
             "EvalActionName": "iam:GetObject",
             "EvalResourceName": "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket",
             "EvalDecision": "allowed",
             "MatchedStatements": [
                 {
                     "SourcePolicyId": "AdministratorAccess",
                     "StartPosition": {
                         "Line": 3,
                         "Column": 17
                     },
                     "EndPosition": {
                         "Line": 8,
                         "Column": 6
                     }
                 }
             ],
             "MissingContextValues": []
         },
         {
             "EvalActionName": "iam:PutObject",
             "EvalResourceName": "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket",
             "EvalDecision": "allowed",
             "MatchedStatements": [
                 {
                     "SourcePolicyId": "AdministratorAccess",
                     "StartPosition": {
                         "Line": 3,
                         "Column": 17
                     },
                     "EndPosition": {
                         "Line": 8,
                         "Column": 6
                     }
                 }
             ],
             "MissingContextValues": []
         }
     ]
 }
```

What I am missing?

Here is my policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket",
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket",
                "arn:aws:s3:::somebucket/*",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your policy works perfectly fine for me (once I remove a couple of errant commas). I can run `aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket . --recursive` without error. Do you have a Bucket Policy on the bucket that might be interfering?

Comment: No, Bucket policy says `No` in console.

Comment: Well, it works fine for me. You should confirm that the policy is on the user and you are using credentials associated with that user. Start by using `aws s3 ls` to confirm that you can list the contents of the bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. My `aws-cli` was set up with incorrect user and was trying to list bucket with it. As S3 bucket names are global, there was no error thrown on that. After I specified correct profile, all went fine.

BTW, in such a case one can just add another user in bucket ACL permissions and that's it!

[image]

For that one should now its Canonical User ID, which can be found out like this

```
aws s3api list-buckets
```

[This AWS thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=701604) helped me.